# Zend Debugger breaks at every Zend Framework class

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I recently installed PDT Helios and now when using the debugger, it will break everytime a new class is referenced in the stack for all of Zend Framework classes. As far as I can tell, it is only done with ZF classes, and not my application's own classes.

If I have no breakpoints set, it will run continuously until completion but when I set a breakpoint, it stops at every Zend Class along the way.

I never had this problem before. Any workaround for it?

Comment: have the same problem, annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in an update.

See http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=548959#msg_548959