# How do I upgrade from Eclipse PDT 2.2.0 build 20100617-1415 to fix the Zend Debugger ZF break-on-every-file bug?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have Eclipse PDT 2.2.0 and my Zend Debugger breaks at the start of every Zend Framework related file.  There is already another SO post [Zend Debugger breaks at every Zend Framework class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261038/zend-debugger-breaks-at-every-zend-framework-class) about that issue, and the solution was to update to a later build; however, I don't seem to be able to do that.

After downloading the latest 2.2.0 All-in-One package from http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/, I've tried **Help->Check for Updates**, which fails and reports the following:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>     Software being installed: Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.php 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
>     Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1276791101682 (SharedProfile_epp.package.php 1.0.0.1276791101682)
>     Only one of the following can be installed at once:
>       Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0520 (epp.package.php 1.3.0.20100617-0520)
>       Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.php 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1276791101682 (SharedProfile_epp.package.php 1.0.0.1276791101682)
>       To: epp.package.php [1.3.0.20100617-0520]

Despite the "helpful" error message, I wasn't sure what to do, so I tried following the instructions mentioned in [Zend Debugger breaks at every Zend Framework class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261038/zend-debugger-breaks-at-every-zend-framework-class).  I downloaded the recommended [201006170734](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/?showAll=1&hlbuild=M201006170734&sortBy=date&project=pdt#M201006170734) SDK as well as the latest [201010110334](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/?showAll=1&hlbuild=M201010110334&sortBy=date&project=pdt#M201010110334) SDK.

Each time, I extracted the archives into `c:\program files\eclipse\dropins\` and started eclipse from the command line using the `--clean` flag.  Regardless, **Help->About Eclipse** still shows build id 20100617-1415 and my debugging sessions still break on every single Zend Framework file despite there not being any breakpoints set up in there.

I can't believe it's this difficult to perform a simple upgrade.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI,

I really am not familiar with the Eclipse IDE for PHP ... but seeing as you have no lead here at all, I'll at least try and give you some potential issues to investigate.

First of, the error message you get is Eclipse telling you that there are conflicting dependencies between the "old" and "new" version of the software you're upgrading. I've never understood how a plugin that's going to be uninstalled anyway can cause conflicts, but that seldom happens. What you can try in these cases is to simply uninstall the offending plugin and restarting your Eclipse before trying to install it from scratch. In your case,

- go to "Help > Install New Software..."
- click on the somewhat hard to see link "already installed" at the bottom right of that popup.
- select the plugin you want to remove from the list of installed software (in your case, it seems to be `epp.package.php`, version 1.3.0.20100617) and hit the "Uninstall" button
- restart Eclipse

Now if you go again to the list of installed software, you shouldn't see that plugin anymore. You can now try and install the new version (1.3.1.20100916).

If that doesn't work, you'll most likely have to install your Eclipse from scratch and only install the latest version of the Eclipse PDT since they don't seem to support updating.

If all else fail, try and get in contact with the development team of the PDT; they should be monitoring the [official Eclipse PDT forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=85&S=7e905701ec83ad208f0adddf219a49b6).

Sorry if that doesn't help, I can only provide you with general information as I never dealt with the PDT myself.

**edit** In order to install a "clean" Eclipse with the latest PDT version :

- Download the latest "Eclipse classic" for your architecture from the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-361/heliossr1)
- Download the latest "all-in-one update site" build of the PDT from their [PDT download page](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) (here is the link for the latest (at the time of writing) [2.2.0 version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/pdt/downloads/drops/2.2.0/M201010110334/pdt-Update-M201010110334.zip)
- Unzip your eclipse classic in a directory of your choice
- Launch Eclipse.exe
- Select "Help > Install New Software..."
- Click "Add..." on the right of this screen
- Click the "Archive" button and browse to the location of the "all-in-one update site"  you downloaded earlier
- You should now be displayed the list of PDT bits you can install, select whichever you need (I tried with the "all-in-one SDK" choice) and validate

The installation takes a while, but you should now have an Eclipse with the latest PDT build... I could go that far on my machine... but as I am not familiar with the PDT, could not try and see whether your use case works :).

Comment: I tried what you suggested but "Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers" is the only thing listed under "Installed Software" and it does not let me uninstall it.  However, I do already have what I presume is the latest version (I got the 2.2.0 All-in-One from here: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/), yet it says it's from June of 2010.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Seems like this is their version of the simultaneous Eclipse release, 2010. Maybe you could try to install a "clean" Eclipse with their latest maintenance build from scratch (note that you can keep the same workspace). I'm editing my post with the instructions in case you don't know how or someone else has the same issue and want a quick wrap-up :).

Comment: Thanks but Eclipse is still not satisfied.  I was able to install 3.6.1 but could not install the PDT plugin.  I got this:  Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) Runtime Feature 2.2.1.v20101001-2300-7L7J1F8NcJTJTJJT9cmJJ (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 2.2.1.v20101001-2300-7L7J1F8NcJTJTJJT9cmJJ)
  Missing requirement: PDT Core Plug-in 2.2.1.v20101001-2300 (org.eclipse.php.core 2.2.1.v20101001-2300) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: That's strange ... I could install everything with just the steps I described here. In your case, you have to download and install DLTK core prior to installing PDT. Download the update site from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/dltk/downloads/drops/R2.0/R-2.0-201006161315/dltk-R-2.0-201006161315-updateSite.zip and add it in the available updates sites in order to install "DLTK core" from it. If it still complains about dependencies, check that "Helios" is ticked in "Help > Install New Software... > Available Update Sites" before trying to install.

Comment: Apparently I cannot install the DLTK because I do not have the DLTK: "Missing requirement: Dynamic Languages Toolkit Core 1.0.0.v20090617-1157 (org.eclipse.dltk.core 1.0.0.v20090617-1157) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore 0.0.0' but it could not be found".  :(

Comment: Nope, here it is asking you to install yet another dependency. it really seems like you're missing the "helios" update site, otherwise it would be able to resolve these dependencies automatically. could you go to "help > install new software", follow the link "available update sites" and check that "helios" is ticked?

Comment: The only options under "Available Update Sites" are the archives I've downloaded and added manually.  There is no option for "Helios".

Comment: Hum, this explains that :) add the update sitz "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/" in the list of available sites and try installing dltk again :)

Comment: I added the Helios update site and just tried PDT again.  Since the missing Helios site was causing all of the dependency issues, I assumed perhaps that it would take care of the DLTK dependency for me.  It did, PDT got installed, and now I can debug my Zend Framework projects without it breaking on the first line of every ZF file.  For someone who has never used PDT, you did a hell of a job helping me out despite all the iterations!  Thanks so much - I wish I had set the bounty higher so you could get more rep.

Comment: Glad I could help :). I am not familiar with the PDT (in fact I never wrote a single PHP line :p), but I do am an Eclipse committer and thus sometimes have this kind of issues myself ^^. I still wonder why you did not have the Helios update site by default, I've never downloaded a "classic" Eclipse without this update site set.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on Helios running under Windows seven, changing the PDT repository address (Window/Help/Install New Softwares/Add Software Sites) from [the Helios releases](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/) to the [PDT last update](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/2.2/milestones) and restarting Eclipse solved that issue, as according to [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Eclipse_3.6_.2F_Helios_.2F_PDT_2.2).